# How can i count unique visitors on my website?

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller

I am looking for a way to count unique visitors on my website and then display it on the website. How can I do that?

This is what the code needs to do:

1. Once the page loads, check if the visitor is new or old
2. If he is old, ignore him
3. If he is new, in mssql it need to add 1 to my value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a session cookie for this. Every time someone connects to your service you check for that cookie and increment the counter if the cookie does not exist yet.

Here's how you define a cookie, let's call it "hasVisited":

```
HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie("hasVisited");
aCookie.Value = true;
aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(100);
Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
```

You then read it like this:

```
if(Request.Cookies["hasVisited"] == null)
{
    // increment counter and add cookie for future reference...
}
```

You could also work with IP and MAC-Addresses (being less reliable due to firewalls etc.). To get the IP of the client use:

```
var remoteIpAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;
```

For the MAC address I suggest you look at

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/2088/how-to-get-mac-address-of-client-machine

for further information.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Google Analytics JS script to count visitors. It is more reliable then what you could code and has everything you may wish for.

You must use cookies to keep track of returning visitors and distinguish plain requests from actual users. That's not trivial because some users may remove cookies and such. Google Analytics is pretty smart in those cases, too, and keeps the counters separate so you don't get confused (and false positives).

To display that visitor number you'll find plenty examples for Google Analytics + some Javascript.

Comment: I know about google analytics, but i'm not looking for that soulution right now :)

Comment: Ah, ok :) That was just the first thing that came to my mind. Do you have some code to show?

Comment: i dont :) I am not sure where to start :)